# React-Select Duplicates and Use Case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, contentful

I'm using react-select to help create a filtering system for my website. However, I have some issues with it at the moment.

Background:

- I'm retrieving data from Contentful API
- Using Next js
- Using getStaticProps

Here is my code for contentful:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const client = createClient({
    space: process.env.TOKEN,
    accessToken: process.env.TOKEN,
  });

  const res = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: "indieProjects",
  });

  return {
    props: {
      indieProjects: res.items,
    },
  };
}
```

Here is my code for React-select

```
 <Select
   isMulti
   placeholder="Search..."
   options={indieProjects.map((items) => {
     return { label: items.fields.type, label: items.fields.type };
   })}
            
/>
```

My first issue is.. when using this I get duplicates pop up when I only want 1 of each to show. [I have attached an example of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xte8b.png) . I know that it is to do with the options and mapping over indieProjects - but Im not sure the best way to fix it.

My second issue is... how do I then render the component once the selection has been made? It will be multi-select so the user can select as many options.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: A separate question per issue is preferred since it makes it more helpful to others with similar problems. Two questions also make it hard to accept an answer if two separate answers are provided for each question. Lastly, you're not giving us much information about what kind of debugging you have done, e.g, what's happening on the network? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Agreed you'll get better answers by separating these into two questions. People who might be able to answer part one will see that maybe they can't answer the second part and not bother answering at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest memoizing the options for react select if you need to filter them (which you do in order to get rid of your duplicates.)

Something like this should solve your first problem. for your second problem, you should add an onChange function and assign a value to your Select. I would suggest using useState for this. (using state will also give you access to the value(s) that they choose)

Also a huge problem it seems you have is that you use `label` and `label` instead of `label` and `value` for your options object.

```
const [state,setState] = useState([])
const options = useMemo(
  () =>
    ([...new Set(indieProjects.map(item=>item.fields.type))]).map((type) => {
      return { label: type, value: type };
    }),
  [indieProjects]
);
return (
 <Select
   isMulti
   onChange={(e)=> e && setState(e)}
   value={state}
   placeholder="Search..."
   options={options}        
/>)
```

Here is a link to a code sandbox with the Select rendering.

https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-leftpad-l2pzq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks so much! Never used useMemo -> will look into it now!

Comment: Sorry, could you explain the second part on how to get it to render? How would I use the useState( in this case setState)? If it helps I can create another question? @Daniel

Comment: @FamousLastWords Added a code sandbox for you

Comment: Not sure if that works.. So I know my issue is that with getStaticProps it wont work when the user makes a search. I would then need to remove the getstatic props. The only example I can see on contentful docs is using GraphQL - which I will need to learn.

Comment: @FamousLastWords searching is built into react-select though? (as long as you have all of the options available)

Comment: So searching works but I'm struggling to find a way to match the results with items on Contentful. So the search bar works but I'm not sure how to take the value(s) of that and use it with the Contentful API. Since its coming from getStaticProp would that not mean its not able to change with user interactions?

Comment: @FamousLastWords I don't fully understand what you are trying to do... Are you trying to render a component based on their react-select choice?